# Ruby | badRequest: The requested conversion is not supported. (Google::Apis::ClientError) | While exporting file

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have some problem with **export_file** method. It's seem like it work time to time
Here is my full code

```
OOB_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = 'private/credentials-2.json'
TOKEN_PATH = 'private/tokens.yaml'
USER_ID = ENV['USER']

class GoogleDriveGetFiles

  def call(file_name)
    @file_name = file_name
    credentials = auth
    drive_service = drive_service_auth(credentials)
    file_id = get_file(drive_service)
    write_in_file(file_id, drive_service)
  end

  private

  def auth
    client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH)
    token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new(file: TOKEN_PATH)
    authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new(client_id, SCOPE, token_store)
    credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(USER_ID)
    if credentials.nil?
      url = authorizer.get_authorization_url(base_url: OOB_URI)
      puts "Open #{url} in your browser and enter the resulting code:"
      code = gets.chomp
      credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
        user_id: USER_ID, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI)
      end
      
      credentials
  end
    
  def drive_service_auth(credentials)
    drive_service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
    drive_service.authorization = credentials
    
    drive_service
  end
    
  def get_file(drive_service)
    files = drive_service.list_files(fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)').files
    
    file_id = nil
    files.each do |file|
      if file.name == @file_name
        file_id = file.id
        puts file.name
        break
      end
    end
    file_id
  end

  def write_in_file(file_id, drive_service)
    # binding.pry
    file = drive_service.get_file(file_id)
    File.write("output/#{@file_name}.txt", drive_service.export_file(file_id, 'text/plain'))
    puts 'Succefully write in file'
  end

end
```

get_file method works properly, but export_file doesn't

I have tried debugging the library but cannot pinpoint the exact cause of the error. Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

I worked until 7:30PM, now I have error.
Here is stacktrace of my error.

```
/home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.11.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:239:in `check_status': badRequest: The requested conversion is not supported. (Google::Apis::ClientError)
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.11.0/lib/google/apis/core/api_command.rb:135:in `check_status'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.11.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:202:in `process_response'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.11.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:321:in `execute_once'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.11.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in do_retry'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:61:in `block in retriable'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `times'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `retriable'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.11.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:123:in `block in do_retry'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:61:in `block in retriable'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `times'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `retriable'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.11.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:113:in `do_retry'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.11.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:104:in `execute'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.11.0/lib/google/apis/core/base_service.rb:418:in `execute_or_queue_command'
        from /home/we/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/google-apis-drive_v3-0.37.0/lib/google/apis/drive_v3/service.rb:1064:in `export_file'
        from /home/we/ruby/parse/google_drive_get_file.rb:64:in `write_in_file'
        from /home/we/ruby/parse/google_drive_get_file.rb:19:in `call'
        from main.ruby:10:in `<main>'
```

**UPDATE**
I found out that if I give public premmison to read only, it's not work. But if I give public premmision to change file, it's work!

Comment: If you try the export method through [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) does it work? Also, what type of file are you trying to export?

Comment: @LorenaGomez it's standart google docs file (that create by default). Also I can download it as text using web gui

Comment: I found out that if I give public premmison to read only, it's not work. But if I gave public premmision to change file, it's work!

Comment: I was doing some testing and when the file is shared publicly to 'viewer' it works without issues. Just to make sure that is the solution, the error you reported above, did it happen only with certain files? It could also be related to the file size, the exported content is limited to 10MB.

Comment: I dont know, maybe it was something on google side error, but after i change public view that message not appear anymore (i don't change my code)